# React PureComponent (un)expected behaviour

Tags: reactjs, performance

I'm trying to understand in practice how `shallow` prop comparison works in `React.PureComponent` in case of prop being an object. I have read two interpretations:

- Only the fact whether the new prop is pointing to the same object,
  i.e. the reference stays unchanged, is checked.
- Properties of the object are compared.

In any case, my example should meet either of the interpretations. But, for some reason, my component still re-renders.

Here's what I have.

**Parent.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {getItems} from '../utils/data'
import Child from './Child'
import Filter from './Filter'

class Parent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    filter: undefined,
    items: []
  }

  handleFilterChange = filter => {
    this.setState(
      {filter},
      () => getItems(filter, items => this.setState({items})
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Filter filter={this.state.filter} onFilterChange={this.handleFilterChange} />
        <Child items={this.state.items} />
      </div> 
    )
  }
}
```

**Child.js**

```
class Child extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      console.log('RENDER')
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

When a `filter` is changed, it triggers the `render` method of the `Parent` component twice:

1. When the state of the `Parent` is updated with the new `filter`.
2. When the new `items` are fetched and the state of `Parent` is updated.

Now, because my `Child` is a `PureComponent`, I would expect it to be re-rendered only the second time, not the first. But in fact in re-renders both times.

`items` is an array of objects, e.g.:

```
[
  {title: 'aaa', index: 0, group: 'filter1'},
  {title: 'bbb', index: 1, group: 'filter2'}
]
```

So, I would expect `PureComponent` to NOT render if only the `filter` is updated, because:

- `items` is the same array that is stored in the state of the `Parent` component;
- The contents of the `items` array don't change, i.e. the objects are exactly the same.

Why does my `Child` component render twice then?

Comment: Can you show us what does your `getItems` implementation look like?

Comment: Hi @Jackyef. `getItems` fetches new items from `Firestore`. So, when new `items` are returned, it's essentially a new array.

Comment: The second argument to `setState` should be a callback function. Is your `getItems` function returning a function? If not, try changing that line to `() => getItems(filter, items => this.setState({items});`

Comment: You're right, it's a typo on my behalf. I corrected it now. But the problem is not here. I want to know why my `Child` component is updated even before I get the new `items`.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code you provided. Strange. PureComponent should not behave like this, I've made a snippet to confirm that a PureComponent won't be re-rendered if it's props did not update. https://codesandbox.io/s/yvq1pkpnyj

Comment: Could you show what's inside `Filter`?

Comment: is `<Child items={items} />` really `<Child items={this.state.items} />`?

Comment: Yes, your codesandbox example is what I expect the behaviour to be, but in my case it isn't for some reason... `Filter` is essentially a bunch of buttons, each send its value as a `filter` to the `Parent`, nothing more.

Comment: Yes, it should be `<Child items={this.state.items} />` - fixed it, thanks for spotting.

Comment: you pass a filter and a function to `getItems` and it must call the function internally. Have you confirmed that it isn't calling the function twice?

Comment: Yes. If I put a `console.log` in the callback of `getItems`, it logs only once upon receiving the new `items`.